# How to delete in table on row number basis

Tags: c#, sql, database, postgresql

I am under a situation where i have table containing some data which also has primary key ID, and i display that data in datagridview, Now i have to delete any particular row in both datagridview  and table.

Now the code for clicking part is ok , I get the row number and i delete the row corresponding to the Primary key ID in table , But the probe occurs when one row is deleted then let's say i clicked on 3rd row, then go to the table and tried to find the ID(PK) which is 3, and delete it,
But it's not a good way because now the order of table will be

```
1
2   //3 is deleted
4
5
```

So the next time when i click on 4 in data grid view, then it will look for ID=3 (as row number is 3) and hence nothing will be deleted as there is now ID=3 in my table.

So i am looking for a way to delete on row number basis, Not on ID number basis, such that which ever row i click in Data grid view, corresponding row number will be deleted in table also.

My code to delete the row on basis of ID is this :

```
internal void DeleteIndividualParcel(string tableName, string Conx, int number)
{
            //number is the row number clicked in dataGridView
            NpgsqlConnection MyCnx = new NpgsqlConnection(Conx);
            NpgsqlCommand MyCmd;
            List<string> finalList = new List<string>();
            string delete = "";
            delete = "DELETE FROM " + tableName + " WHERE id =" + number + ";";           
            try
            {
                MyCnx.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The connection can't be opened!" + ex.Message);
            }

            MyCmd = new NpgsqlCommand(delete, MyCnx);

            try
            {
                MyCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The query can't be executed from DeleteParcel!" + ex.Message);
            }

            MyCnx.Close();
 }
```

How to change the code to make the row number basis delete ?

Comment: Gotta ask why you're tagging with both MySQL and SQL Server.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen My edit answers you :)

Answer (score 1):

Please DO NOT use this solution. Instead follow the advice from other answers: always keep the primary key in any CRUD operation, so you delete where id=something.

You should always delete on solid criteria, not by a row's position in the table (unless you are just cleaning up part of the table, where this row_number() business comes in very handy). Why is that? You can delete something you did not intend, when:

- Someone modifies the table after you loaded the data, and before you want to delete a record, so the row number in the UI and in the DB don't match
- If you have a sortable table, it's much harder to pass the sorting criteria, instead of just a key value (ID)
- The solution is just ugly

Now then, since this is clearly PostgreSql, this is what you need:

```
DO $$
DECLARE vid INT;
BEGIN
  SELECT tt.id into vid
  from (select id, row_number() over () as rn from testtable) tt
  WHERE tt.rn=2;

  DELETE FROM testtable WHERE testtable.id=vid;
END $$;
```

to delete the 3rd row

Since the 3rd row differs based on how you order the table, if the query that composes that DataGrid has an `Order By`, make sure to include it in the `over()` like this:

```
row_number() over(ORDER BY id) as rn
```

Answer (score 0):

The quickest, easiest, and worst way to handle this would be to re-query the database and rebuild the grid after each delete.

A somewhat less dirty, but also more difficult, method is to remove the item from your list when you remove it from the grid.

Another way would be to put the ID in a hidden column in your grid.

Comment: Please re-read the question carefully, I already delete the row from grid by removing at that position (dataGView.Removeat(number)) and then i try to delete at the same row in table, for the first delete because the ID is arranged in correct order in table, so i delete the ID which has row number selected by user, but after first click the order of ID changes so i cannot delete according to row numbers

Answer (score 0):

Basic Rules:

First of all while doing two way communication between UI and database table, one should be careful about choosing correct column of the table that can uniquely define set of records. So, generally "PK" (Primary Key) column are chosen.

Secondly, while doing any kind of CRUD (Create, Read, Update and Delete) operation both side list should be updated accordingly.

If you are using row number as a key to manipulate database records than make sure that both the list in UI and in DB are synced after every operation.